# Cypher - Order By Degrading the Query Performance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working on a graph DB where an organisation contains 1 Billion Employee records. If I try to order the employees on their performance and get the top 1000 efficient employees, the query is not returning the results. How can I fine tune this.

**My query:**

```
    MATCH (org:Organization{org_guid:"12345"})-[r:EMPLOYED_BY]-(emp:Employee)
    WITH org,r,emp ORDER BY coalesce(r.efficiency,0) DESC
    LIMIT (1000)
    RETURN emp
```

Comment: Forgive me, but is that your exact query ? Just asking because you RETURN something (buyer) that is not featuring in the rest of your query.

Comment: Sorry. Edited the question.

Comment: @JackDaniel What you mean `not returning the results`?

Comment: @stdob-- I am returning top 1000 efficient employees

Comment: Have you setup the correct constraints on your labels? It can help **a lot** in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

Currently in Neo4j `ODRER BY` is not able to use an index, which means it will require a scan, which can result in poor performance for large datasets.

There is an [APOC procedure](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_schema_index_queries), however, that is able to use an index for range search and maintaining order. You would need to refactor your datamodel slightly as you cannot create an index on a relationship property. If instead you wanted to order by `efficiency` as a property on `:Employee`:

First, create an index on `:Employee(efficiency)`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Employee(efficiency);
```

Then,

```
CALL apoc.index.orderedRange('Employee', 'efficiency', 0, 99999, false, 1000) 
YIELD node AS employee
RETURN employee;
```

Another slight complication is that you want descending order, so you would need to store the negative of the efficiency value to get the results in descending order.

Comment: Careful with this one, we've seen some issues with `orderedRange()` in the past, and I don't think they've been fixed. In particular, we saw the procedure working properly immediately after index creation on nodes, but not when new nodes were added to an existing index. I'd stay away from this one until its fixed.